# Capturing specific data from Twitch info?

Tags: javascript, regex

So I have twitch follower data in the format:

```
20Hour Stream w/ @summit1g.
19,075 viewers on summit1g


Untitled Broadcast
6,392 viewers on Trick2g


Vinny || Metal Gear Solid 3: Snake Meeter + More
2,948 viewers on Vinesauce


Isaac Mastery - http://bit.ly/1JwGmnn - #1147
2,862 viewers on Lethalfrag


VIDYA GAEMZ STREAM???
1,554 viewers on Boogie2988


DREAM TEAM ~ 0/10 wins in a row! ~ 230 BR Wins ~ @sxyhxy ┌∩┐(ò_óˇ)
1,098 viewers on sxyhxy
```

I want to know if I can use Regexp to capture the viewer count, the person's channel name, as well as the title of their stream in three separate groups.

I have the following regex: `([^\n]+)\n([^\n]+)\n{2}` which only captures the title and all the below info, but what I want is the viewer count and channel name from that specifically. An ideal capture output would be `20Hour Stream w/ @summit1g.`, `19,075`, and `summit1g` as capture 1-3 respectively.

Is there any way to do this with just regex? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following regex will capture what you what you want: `(.+)\n([\d,]+).+on (\w+)`

Comment: It will fail if the input contains `VIDYA GAEMZ STREAM???[newline]1,554 viewers on Boogie-2988` or `VIDYA GAEMZ STREAM???[newline]1,554 viewers on Boogie 2988`.

Comment: Usernames on twitch don't contain dashes. It worked with every scenario I have tested.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following regex:

```
/(.+)\n(\d+(?:,\d{3})*)\s+viewers on\s+(\w+)/
```

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/cK4nA7/4)

Note that `.` is actually equal to `[^\n]` in JavaScript (as there is no singleline modifier).

The `(.+)` captures the first line, then `\n` proceeds to the next line, `(\d+(?:,\d{3})*)` captures the number with optional thousands, millions, etc.), `\s+` matches 1 or more whitespace characters, and `(\w+)` captures the Twitch ID.

```js
var re = /(.+)\n(\d+(?:,\d{3})*)\s+viewers on\s+(\w+)/g; 
var str = '20Hour Stream w/ @summit1g.\n19,075 viewers on summit1g\n\n\nUntitled Broadcast\n6,392 viewers on Trick2g\n\n\nVinny || Metal Gear Solid 3: Snake Meeter + More\n2,948 viewers on Vinesauce\n\n\nIsaac Mastery - http://bit.ly/1JwGmnn - #1147\n2,862 viewers on Lethalfrag\n\n\nVIDYA GAEMZ STREAM???\n1,554 viewers on Boogie2988';
var m;
 
while ((m = re.exec(str)) !== null) {
    if (m.index === re.lastIndex) {
        re.lastIndex++;
    }
    document.write("channel name: " + m[1] + "<br/>");
  document.write("count: " + m[2] + "<br/>");
  document.write("title: " + m[3] + "<br/><br/>");
}
```

Comment: This is a good answer that works with the multiline flag enabled, but @Dungeonfire already posted an answer that doesn't require it, which works with my code better, sorry...

Comment: But you can remove `^` and `/m` I guess, it is not that important actually. I updated the answer. The most important part is placing capturing groups at the right place with the right pattern. If your titles have spaces, the other suggested regex will fail.

Comment: Ok, I see they cannot contain spaces and conform to `\w+` regex. I updated the answer so as to add more precision.

Answer (score -1):

How about getting this process :

- Capture First line - Followed by \n
- Any amount of characters
- Followed by any amount of spaces
- Follow by sentence 'viewers '
- Capture the name of the streamer

[Demo here](https://regex101.com/r/bK3vP4/3)

Comment: I'd like to do it all in one expression if that's even possible... would there be a way to incorperate this into my original expression?

Comment: Edited for all in one. Missread streamer name part. Anyway Regex below are stronger, I mean more general than mine.